# I want to use shell script output as a input to the makefile variable and pass that as the build parameter in docker build

Tags: docker, travis-ci, gnu-make

makefile looks like below

```
BASE_JOB_IMAGE := $(shell ./fetchimageversion.sh >> image.txt)
FILE ?= image.txt
BASE_JOB_IMAGE_NAME=`cat $(FILE)`


docker build \
    --pull \
    --no-cache \
    -t ${APPLICATION}_${TF_VER} \
    --build-arg baseimage=$(BASE_JOB_IMAGE_NAME)
```

But I am not getting the expected output in travis logs.

```
docker build \
    --pull \
    --no-cache \
    --build-arg baseimage=`cat image.txt` \
```

When used as BASE_JOB_IMAGE := $(shell ./fetchimageversion.sh) I do see the output of the script
output but whole script execution result is set to the variable which also result in error in travis log wihth --build-arg baseimage= \ being blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First that can't be the makefile; you have a target with no recipe.  I assume that the `docker` command is in a recipe.  Please be sure to provide enough of an example to constitute a functional test.

Second, when you run `make` what output do you see?  When asking for help it's best to include the command you typed, the output you got (if it's a lot of output at least show the errors and few lines before it), and explain what you wanted.  You should cut and paste this into your question: don't use screenshots and don't paraphrase/retype it where you might introduce subtle differences that might completely change the possible problem.

Third, why do you write the output to a static file but then set a variable and refer to the variable for the rest of the makefile?

Fourth, why do you use `?=` to define the filename?  Do you expect to want to allow an environment variable to override the filename?  That won't work if you're writing to a static filename in the previous command.

Fifth, why are you using append-to `>>` when writing the file?  If the file already exists this means you'll have multiple lines of content in it.

Try writing your makefile like this:

```
FILE = input.txt
BASE_JOB_IMAGE := $(shell ./fetchimageversion.sh >$(FILE))
BASE_JOB_IMAGE_NAME = `cat $(FILE)`

...rest of makefile...
```

and if that doesn't work, please provide more details as discussed in the first two paragraphs.

**ETA**

But, I don't know why you're going through this extra effort of writing to a file.  Why not just keep the output in a variable?

```
BASE_JOB_IMAGE_NAME := $(shell ./fetchimageversion.sh)

...rest of makefile...
```